# How to add associations to module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, module, ruby-on-rails-4

How to achive this sturcture in Rails?

```
User
 has_one :health
Health
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :weights
 has_many :diseases

Health::Weight
 belongs_to :health
Health::Diseases
 belongs_to :health

users
 health_id:integer
healths
 id:integer
health_weights
 current:integer
 health_id:integer
health_diseases
 name:text
 health_id:integer
```

When I generate `r g model Health::Weight current:integer` my `Health` is a module without ActiveRecord:

```
module Health
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'health_'
  end
end
```

I this good approach?

Comment: So, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

1. A given User's health profile can have many health characteristics (weight, disease, etc).
2. You want to put models corresponding to health characteristics within a module to clearly separate them from other parts of your app

---

This is a good case actually for using a "Health" module as you did for Health::Weight and Health::Diseases.

But you should not use a model called Health as your model linking users to their health characteristics.

This leads first to confusion in terms of semantics but also it won't work in code: Health cannot be at the same time an ActiveRecord::Base subclass (or other 'ORM class') and the module encapsulating other tables like Weight and Diseases.

---

=> Replace your Health model with a clearer model name that clearly states that it is a link between a User and its health characteristics (weight, diseases, etc.). For example UserHealthProfile.

The end structure would be:

```
    class User
      has_one :user_health_profile
    end

    class UserHealthProfile
      belongs_to :user
      has_one    :weight 
      has_many   :diseases
    end

    module Health
      def self.table_name_prefix
        'health_'
      end
    end       

    class Health::Weight
      belongs_to :user_health_profile
    end

    class Health::Disease
      belongs_to :user_health_profile
    end
```

---

You may also put your UserHealthProfile model inside the Health module like so:

```
    class Health::UserHealthProfile
    end
```

---

NB: When encapsulating models into modules, you may need to add a class_name argument when defining your associations but this will depend on your actual module structure.

Example:

```
    # let's say UserHealthProfile doesn't belong to the Health module
    class UserHealthProfile
      belongs_to :user
      has_one    :weight,   class_name: Health::Weight
      has_many   :diseases, class_name: Health::Disease
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to generate your models/controllers within modules, change this:

```
rails g model Health::Weight current:integer
```

to

```
rails g model health/weight current:integer
```

But personally, I wouldn't bother, unless you truly have so many models that you just can't keep track of them all.

Answer (score 0):

Not good at all.

Modelling is to try to abstract real world objects. None of your models is real world one except User.

How can an user has one health? How can health have many weight? How can health have many disease? They are all not something understandable in real world.

My suggestion is not to make models like a tree, but start from real problems to solve.

For example, an user may have many weight records. An user may have many disease.

Comment: I want to separate health related models from user table and have maybe not exactly Health model but something similar which connect these models with User model. This is because of the privacy law which I have to abide.

Comment: @regedarek, I can't judge without knowing the real problem domain. But you can hide anything you want with plain model names.

Comment: Probably a better wording for op would be `HealthStatus` or physical status or something aong these lines. A person can have a health status. Whether it makes sense to separate these from the user is another topic.